# SQL: Find all rows in a table when the rows are a foreign key in another table

Tags: sql

The **caveat** here is I must complete this with only the following tools:

1. The basic SQL construct: `SELECT FROM .. AS WHERE..`. Distinct is ok.
2. Set operators: `UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT`
3. Create temporary relations: `CREATE VIEW... AS ...`
4. Arithmetic operators like `<, >, <=, ==` etc.
5. Subquery can be used only in the context of `NOT IN` or a subtraction operation. I.e. (`select ... from... where not in (select..`.)

I can NOT use any `join, limit, max, min, count, sum, having, group by, not exists, any exists, count, aggregate` functions or anything else not listed in 1-5 above.

**Schema**:

```
People (id, name, age, address)

Courses (cid, name, department)

Grades (pid, cid, grade)
```

I satisfied the query but I used not exists (which I can't use). The sql below shows only people who took every class in the Courses table:

```
select People.name from People
where not exists
(select Courses.cid from Courses
where not exists
(select grades.cid from grades
where grades.cid = courses.cid and grades.pid = people.id))
```

Is there way to solve this by using *not in* or some other method that I am allowed to use? I've struggled with this for hours. If anyone can help with this goofy obstacle, I'll gladly upvote your answer and select your answer.

Comment: So you can't use `join` or aggregate functions? Maybe you can use `except` to identify students with an incomplete  list, then use `NOT IN` against that

Comment: How would I go about seeing who didn't take every course in the course table? Having trouble with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nick.McDermaid said you can use `except` to identify students that are missing classes and `not in` to exclude them.

1 Get the complete list with a cartesian product of `people x courses`. This is what `grades` would look like if every student has taken every course.

```
create view complete_view as
    select people.id as pid, courses.id as cid
    from people, courses
```

2 Use `except` to identify students that are missing at least one class

```
create view missing_view as select distinct pid from (
    select pid, cid from complete_view
    except
    select pid, cid from grades
) t
```

3 Use `not in` to select students that aren't missing any classes

```
select * from people where id not in (select pid from missing_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick suggests, you can use EXCEPT in this case. Here is the sample:

```
select People.name from People
EXCEPT  
select People.name from People AS p
join Grades AS g on g.pid = p.id
join Courses as c on c.cid = g.cid
```

Comment: Thanks but the select statement after EXCEPT simply shows a list of people who have taken *any* course in the courses table. I need to find people who have either taken *every* course in the courses table **or** find people who have not taken *every* course in the courses table.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn the first `not exists` into `not in` using a constant value.

```
select *
from People a
where 1 not in (
    select 1 
    from courses b
    ...
```